# $.getScript callback function won't work?

Tags: jquery

Im trying to implement [this](http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.co.il/2010/01/retrieve-youtube-video-title.html) example, but with "$.getScript":  and for some reason, it wont work....

this is my code :

```
function youtubeFeedCallback(data) {
    var s = '';
    s += '<img src="' + data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url + '" width="' + data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].width + '" height="' + data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].height + '" alt="' + data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].yt$name + '" align="right"/>';
    s += '<b>Title:</b> ' + data.entry.title.$t + '<br/>';
    s += '<b>Author:</b> ' + data.entry.author[0].name.$t + '<br/>';
    s += '<b>Published:</b> ' + new Date(data.entry.published.$t).toLocaleDateString() + '<br/>';
    s += '<b>Duration:</b> ' + Math.floor(data.entry.media$group.yt$duration.seconds / 60) + ':' + (data.entry.media$group.yt$duration.seconds % 60) + ' (' + data.entry.media$group.yt$duration.seconds + ' seconds)<br/>';
    if (data.entry.gd$rating) {
        s += '<b>Rating:</b> ' + data.entry.gd$rating.average.toFixed(1) + ' out of ' + data.entry.gd$rating.max + ' (' + data.entry.gd$rating.numRaters + ' ratings)<br/>';
    }
    s += '<b>Statistics:</b> ' + data.entry.yt$statistics.favoriteCount + ' favorite(s); ' + data.entry.yt$statistics.viewCount + ' view(s)<br/>';
    s += '<br/>' + data.entry.media$group.media$description.$t.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') + '<br/>';
    s += '<br/><a href="' + data.entry.media$group.media$player.url + '" target="_blank">Watch on YouTube</a>';
    document.write(s);
}



$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getScript('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gzDS-Kfd5XQ?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=youtubeFeedCallback', function () {
        alert(1); //This function is placed in jsPlugin.js

    });

});
```

the alert does go well, Im getting the alert, and on FireBug i do see the GET method, but it wont execute the "callback" function.. I dont see it pasting it on my site...

any ideas why ?!`

Comment: AFAIK, `getScript` function downloads the script, but does not execute it, even if it contains `$(document).ready` , you have to call `youtubeFeedCallback` explicitly in your `getScript` success callback i.e. after `alert` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is jsonp.

Try:

```
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gzDS-Kfd5XQ?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?', youtubeFeedCallback);
```

***[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/d48LC/)***

Comment: ok, it loads the file alright, but it seems like it direct me to some other page, and then execute the callback .. I want that it will stay in the same page, and paste the code in the script like it shown in the link example (see AJAX EXAMPLE in the link above..)

Comment: thanks for the demo, it does load the file, but it replaces the page I am working on.. I want it to work in the same page..

Comment: @thormayer It does not redirect, you need to do your work for the callback function to decide which part to replace. I think you are meaning by `document.write(s)` which replaced your page, but this is not redirection also.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.getJSON()`. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ for more information and look for JSONP.

Comment: @willem , `getJson` do not download the scripts.

Comment: Then that is another problem. .getJSON() is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an error in the JavaScript that is fetched, it will not callback properly.

Note in the documentation (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)  the 2nd parameter callback function is called "success"

> As of jQuery 1.5, you may use .fail() to account for errors:

```
$.getScript("path/to/script.js", function() {
    console.log("Script loaded and no errors");
}).fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    console.log("Script loaded but error occurred:");
    console.log(exception);
});
```